# ドキュメントルート以下のGitローカルリポジトリの安全性について

Tags: git

現在以下のような構成で開発を行っています。(ドキュメントルートは/var/www/html/)

- /var/www/

  - remote.git
  - html/

    - .git
    - index.php
    - style.css

ローカル環境(PC側)から、「/var/www/remote.git」へpushし、「/var/www/html/」でpullすることでデプロイしています。

そこで質問なのですが、ドキュメントルート以下にローカルリポジトリ「.git」が存在している事で、第三者からcloneが実行されてしまうことなど、何か問題はありますでしょうか？

試しに[git clone http://○○.com/.git]のようにしましたが、エラーでcloneは正常に実行されませんでした。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

直接cloneなどの操作はできないはずですが、個々のファイルとしてダウンロード出来る状態にはなるので、HTTPサーバ側で制限してください。デフォルトでは制限されないので、apacheであれば

```
<Location "/.git">
    Require all denied
</Location>
```

nginxであれば

```
location /.git {
    deny all;
}
```

こんな感じです。(試してないので必ず動作を確認してください)

Comment: HTTP経由で個別にダウンロードされるリスクがありましたね。
ファイル名がハッシュ化されているものもありますが、これもそれ以外にのファイルをダウンロードされてしまった場合、バレてしまうんでしょうか？
いずれにしても、webサーバー側で制限した方が良さそうですね。
私の方では、ご回答いただく前に取り急ぎの対応として、.git以下を再帰的に[グループ]、[その他]の権限を0に設定しました。

Comment: ファイルなどは`.git/objects/`内でハッシュ化されたファイル名になっていますが, `.git/refs/heads/master`を取得すると, 再帰的に辿ってゆくことができます.

Answer (score 0):

UNIXにおいて`.`で始まるファイルは隠しファイルとして扱う風習があります。Webサーバーはこの風習を受けて、外部からのアクセスを禁止しているものもあります。（大多数？）

ですので、gitではなくWebサーバーの設定を確認してください。アクセスが禁止されていれば安全と考えて問題ないでしょう。